# unusual print behavior splwow64.exe

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, printing, print-spooler

In our office we have two software systems that are integral for office function.  A document management system (called LEAP Documents) and a cost recovery system (called SoftLog) for printing/scanning/faxing etc.

The problem is that we have 20 odd new Windows 7 64-bit computers and the LEAP software we use is displaying some unusual printing behaviour when printing documents.
The first print job of MS Word being opens uses the normal spooler, all consecutive jobs are calling splwow64.exe.

The print job prints OK, but the problem is that the Softlog costing software monitors the spooler.  So it's not prompting for cost recovery details for all of the consecutive jobs.

This only happens for documents opened via LEAP.  Other MS word documents on the computers are sending ALL print jobs to the spooler and Softlog is working OK.

Is there a way we can overcome this splwow64.exe issue?  Why is it being called during consecutive print jobs (after the first one) only?

Comment: These official articles might be of interest to you: [Update rollup: Fix printing problems in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647753/en-us); [Splwow64.exe process doesn't end after a print job finishes in the 64-bit version of Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815716/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Looks like you use a 64Bit Office and the other tool is 32Bit. The splwow64.exe is used to allow 32Bit applications to print on a 64Bit Windows.

Comment: OK, is there a workaround at all or is 32-bit our only real option if we're to have these two applications working as intended?

Comment: go back to a 32Bit Windows or ask the developers to create a 64Bit version of the tool.